# MouseEvent('click') fires while Event('click') does not

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events

I am trying to learn some of the basics of [Javascript event-triggering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), trying it out on this very website.

**Procedure:**

On this board's [front page](https://stackoverflow.com/), open the console (`ctrl+shift+K`; I'm on `Firefox`). First, denote

```js
URL='"https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/26/kotlin-1-4-released-to-improve-performance/?cb=1"'
```

Then, run

```js
document.querySelector(`a[href=${URL}]`).click()
```

**result:** I get sent to [the destination](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/26/kotlin-1-4-released-to-improve-performance/?cb=1).

```js
document.querySelector(`a[href=${URL}]`).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
```

**result:** same as above.

```js
document.querySelector(`a[href=${URL}]`).dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```

**result:** the link is *not* opened. I get `true` returned in the console but stay on the page, so the click is apparently not triggered.

**Question:**
What explains the difference in outcome?

Comment: You could inspect some cross-browser libraries to see why this is so.

Comment: Take a look at [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), you can see it inheriting from two lower interfaces (UIEvent and Event), and only MouseEvent has the properties a mouse event needs.

Comment: @Teemu: on its own, this doesn't tell me much: other elements on the page (for instance the `Products` menu at the top) react to both `Event` and `MouseEvent`.